# LyX 2.3.0 with MiKTeX on Windows 10 - Komascript class "scrreprt" not available

Tags: lyx, miktex, koma-script

I have installed [LyX 2.3.0 with MiKTeX](https://www.lyx.org/Download#toc3) on a Windows 10 machine. When opening a template I would like to use I get notified that the respective komascript class "scrreprt" is missing.

So I went for the obvious, opened the MiKTeX-installer and sucessfully installed the komascript package (later on all "koma*" packages).

But after restarting the machine the error remains the same.

Any hints? Do I have to adjust my settings somewhere in LyX?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have you updated your system twice (admin mode and user mode)? See: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/124842).

Comment: Yes, I have updated both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution now. Actually, it was a LyX issue and not only related to MiKTeX!

Here are the steps which have fixed the problem for me:

1. [Install LyX 2.3.0 with MiKTeX](https://www.lyx.org/Download#toc3)
2. Install required Komascript packages with missing classes for MikTeX
3. [Update MikTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/124842) (optional)
4. Reconfigure LyX: Select "Tools > Reconfigure" from the menu
5. Restart Lyx

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Perfect. If it works you could flag your question as solved. You could accept also your own answer. You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It takes two days until I can accept but then I will..